# Can R Markdown display ggplot graphs created within a function?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, r-markdown

I have a function called "my function" which creates a ggplot graph and saves it within the function.

```
#define a function "add_data" to transpose peak values into summary table
my_function <- function(exp, cond) {
  
  #Read in appropriate experiment number
  #Remove first 2 columns
  #Rename first column to "mintime" and convert to minutes
  #Normalize raw fluorescence values
  
  flowdata <- read_csv(paste0(exp, ".csv"))                                  
  title <- cond                                            
  flowdata <- flowdata[, -c(1:2)] %>%
    rename(mintime = 1) %>%
    transform(mintime = mintime / 60)
  flowdata[,-1] <- data.frame(lapply(flowdata[,-1], function(X) X/X[1]))
  
  #Exclude values up to 5 minutes
  #Determine number of peaks per cell
  #Add number of peaks per cell to summary table
  flowdata_cut <- flowdata[which(flowdata$mintime>=5),]
  peak_info <- lapply(flowdata_cut[,-1], findpeaks, threshold=2)
  numberpeak <- unlist(lapply(peak_info, nrow))
  summarypeaks <- add_peaks(summarypeaks, numberpeak, title)
  
  #Prepare data for line graph
  melted <- melt(flowdata, id.vars="mintime")
  
  #####CREATE GRAPH#####
  #Plot graph
  ggplot(data=melted, aes(x=mintime, y=value, group=variable)) + 
    geom_line(show.legend = FALSE) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(3, 12), breaks = seq(3, 12, by = 3)) +
    labs(y="Fluo-4 fluorescence (F/F0)", x = "Time (min)") +            
    ggtitle(title) +                                   
    theme_bw() +
    
    # remove elements we don't need
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
          panel.background = element_blank()) 
  
  
  #####SAVE GRAPH##### 
  #Save line graph as .png file
  ggsave(filename = paste0(exp, "_Line_Graph.jpg"), width = 8, height = 4)
  
  # Return
  return(summarypeaks)
  
}
```

When I knit the document, the ggplot graph doesn't show in my HTML output despite these parameters

```
{r fig.cap="Experiment DATE", results = TRUE, eval = TRUE, echo= FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, error=FALSE}


#Add experiment and condition
summarypeaks <- my_function(1284, "CONDITION")
```

**Is there a way for the R Markdown HTML document to display the outputs of plots created within a function?**

Comment: Your function isn't returning any plot, it's returning `summarypeaks`. You need to get your function to return the plot as well. I would just do something like `return(list(peaks = summarypeaks, plot = plt))`, assuming you store the outcome of your `ggplot` call in a variable `plt`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for pointing that out. It is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way of getting the plot to show even without returning it, by using side effects. Specifically, you need to save your `ggplot` object into some variable, say `p`, and then tell R to print it using `plot()`. You don't need to change anything about how your function returns its results, it will just happen as a side effect. See below an updated version of your function:

```
#define a function "add_data" to transpose peak values into summary table
my_function <- function(exp, cond) {
  
  #Read in appropriate experiment number
  #Remove first 2 columns
  #Rename first column to "mintime" and convert to minutes
  #Normalize raw fluorescence values
  
  flowdata <- read_csv(paste0(exp, ".csv"))                                  
  title <- cond                                            
  flowdata <- flowdata[, -c(1:2)] %>%
    rename(mintime = 1) %>%
    transform(mintime = mintime / 60)
  flowdata[,-1] <- data.frame(lapply(flowdata[,-1], function(X) X/X[1]))
  
  #Exclude values up to 5 minutes
  #Determine number of peaks per cell
  #Add number of peaks per cell to summary table
  flowdata_cut <- flowdata[which(flowdata$mintime>=5),]
  peak_info <- lapply(flowdata_cut[,-1], findpeaks, threshold=2)
  numberpeak <- unlist(lapply(peak_info, nrow))
  summarypeaks <- add_peaks(summarypeaks, numberpeak, title)
  
  #Prepare data for line graph
  melted <- melt(flowdata, id.vars="mintime")
  
  #####CREATE GRAPH#####
  #Plot graph
  p <- ggplot(data=melted, aes(x=mintime, y=value, group=variable)) + 
    geom_line(show.legend = FALSE) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(3, 12), breaks = seq(3, 12, by = 3)) +
    labs(y="Fluo-4 fluorescence (F/F0)", x = "Time (min)") +            
    ggtitle(title) +                                   
    theme_bw() +
    
    # remove elements we don't need
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
          panel.background = element_blank()) 

  plot(p)
  
  #####SAVE GRAPH##### 
  #Save line graph as .png file
  ggsave(filename = paste0(exp, "_Line_Graph.jpg"), width = 8, height = 4)
  
  # Return
  return(summarypeaks)
  
}
```